# Why doesnt max() give me only max values in that column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to learn SQL and have been solving problems on HackerRank. The following problem is to find the hackers with maximum submissions for each date

So I tried this code on mySQL

```
(select distinct hacker_id,submission_date,count(submission_id) as sid,sum(score)
from submissions
group by 1,2
 having sid=max(sid)
order by 2)
```

It does not give me any output. So I changed the code further to

```
select distinct x.sdate as sd, max(x.subs) as sb
from
(select distinct s.submission_date as sdate,count(distinct s.submission_id) as subs,h.hacker_id as hid,h.name as name
from submissions as s
join hackers as h on s.hacker_id=h.hacker_id
group by 1,3,4
order by s.submission_date,subs desc,h.hacker_id asc)x
group by 1
```

which gives me the date and the maximum count. But the moment I add a name column to the same code it gives me all the submissions for that particular date rendering the max function useless.

Can some explain in detail how this works not for just this problem but so that I can understand the concept of why the first code never gave results and the second code gives unnecessary output.

Thank a ton in advance.

Comment: May I please know what is the reason for putting this query as off-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following query:

```
SELECT
    SUBMISSION_DATE,
    HACKER_ID,
    NAME,
    SUBS
FROM
( SELECT
    S.SUBMISSION_DATE,
    S.HACKER_ID,
    H.NAME   AS NAME,
    RANK() OVER(
        PARTITION BY S.SUBMISSION_DATE
        ORDER BY
            SUBS DESC
    ) AS RN,
    SUBS
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            S.SUBMISSION_DATE   AS SDATE,
            COUNT(DISTINCT S.SUBMISSION_ID) AS SUBS,
            S.HACKER_ID
        FROM
            SUBMISSIONS S
        GROUP BY
            S.SUBMISSION_DATE,
            S.HACKER_ID
    ) S
JOIN HACKERS AS H ON S.HACKER_ID = H.HACKER_ID)
WHERE
             RN = 1;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you. Basically as @Gordon said works only for higher versions of MySQL. So I applied the same concept of Rank() in Orcale. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one row, use `limit`:

```
select hacker_id, count(*) as cnt, sum(score) as score
from submissions
group by hacker_id
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

If you want all hackers i the event of ties, then in MySQL 8+, use `rank()`:

```
select h.*
from (select hacker_id, count(*) as cnt, sum(score) as score,
             rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from submissions
      group by hacker_id
     ) h
where seqnum = 1;
```

This is a little bit more cumbersome in older versions of MySQL.

Comment: Yes. you are right. I used Oracle instead. Worked. Thank you.

Comment: @PrinceRaja . . . If this works, I am surprised that you accepted a more complicated answer posted seven minutes later.  Of course, as the OP you are free to accept any answer you like.